# Persist button selections when changing pages with pagination (But not on refresh)

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a table with pagination and a column that has 2 buttons you can toggle between for each row.

The buttons are pre-selected according to data from the database:

```
@foreach($rows as $row)
  <tr>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button {{$row->type === "option1" ? "selected" : ""}}>Option 1</button>
        <button {{$row->type === "option2" ? "selected" : ""}}>Option 2</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

The user can select choices accross the table, then he has a "save" button that saves all the updated selections.

The problem is that when the pagination link is clicked, the selections aren't saved.

I can save the data in a session, then merge the data from the DB data, and render the correct selections.

But I want to make it behave like it only saves the selections until a refresh. How can I do that? Persist the selections and also make a distinction between the pagination action and a refresh (or tab/browser closed)?